# Using PyObject_IsInstance

Tags: python, types

My application embeds python by dynamically loading it. I need to obtain the values from the dictionary of the script being executed.

```
pFnPyDict_GetItemString *pFGetItemString = NULL;

pFGetItemString = (pFnPyDict_GetItemString *)::GetProcAddress(hModulePython, PyDict_GetItemString);

if (pFGetItemString)
{
    PyObject  *pGet = pFGetItemString(pLocals, pVar);

    if (pGet)
    {
        //The following code will not work as PyInt_Check is a macro
        pFnPyInt_Check *pIsInt = (pFnPyInt_Check *)::GetProcAddress(hModulePython, "PyInt_Check");

        if (PyInt_Check(get))
        {

        }

        // There fore i am using PyObject_IsInstance
        pFnPyObject_IsInstance *pFIsInstance = (pFnPyObject_IsInstance*)::GetProcAddress(hModulePython, "PyObject_IsInstance");

        if (pFIsInstance)
        {           
            int i = pFIsInstance(pGet, (PyObject*)&PyInt_Type); ----> the problem is here.  This call fails. 
        } 
    }
}
```

How do I specify the second parameter to PyObject_IsInstance? Here i want to check if the value in pGet is of type int.

Comment: Is there actually a question here?

Comment: just edited the above post to make the actual question visible

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to check for `ints`? If so you're better off using [`PyInt_Check`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/int.html#PyInt_Check) instead.

*Additional:* Some advice, that you didn't ask for but which might help you. :) Are you using C or C++. If it's the later, consider using [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/) instead of the Python C API — it will make things a lot easier. Exposing functions and classes is trivial with Boost.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the correct approach here is to include the header file and use `PyInt_Check()`.

I assume that you have not included the Python C API header file because you don't want to use implicit linking. But you are making life hard for yourself by trying to work without the header file. Just because you include the header file, doesn't mean that the DLL functions will be implicitly linked to your program. This will only happen if you actually call some of the functions in the DLL.

If you want to be 100% sure that you don't implicitly link to the DLL then simply ensure that you don't link the .lib file.

Comment: Thanks. I had included the header file and used PyInt_Check(pGet) before. It compiled fine but crashed though pGet was valid. I had not linked the lib.

Comment: Sounds like that is your real problem.